# How do I use content_tag with a nested block in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

This is not working for some reason. How do I use a block with `content_tag` like the documentation shows?

```
<% 
flash.each do |name, msg|
  if msg.is_a? Array
    concat content_tag(:div, :id => "flash_#{name}", class: 'alert bg-'+{'notice'=>'success', 'alert'=>'danger', 'error'=>'danger'}[name].to_s) do
      msg.each do |m|
        concat m
        concat "<br>".html_safe
      end
    end
  else
    concat content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", class: 'alert bg-'+{'notice'=>'success', 'alert'=>'danger', 'error'=>'danger'}[name].to_s
  end
end 
%>
```

[Documentation for content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "strong" do -%>
  Hello world!
<% end -%>
 # => <div class="strong">Hello world!</div>
```

My output:

```
<div>{:id=&gt;"flash_alert", :class=&gt;"alert bg-danger"}</div>
```

The line in the controller which is setting the flash:

```
  flash.alert = @tracking.errors.full_messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Rails' concat method and blocks with do...end doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319661/rails-concat-method-and-blocks-with-do-end-doesnt-work)

The block was being passed to `concat`, not `content_tag`. This worked:

```
concat content_tag(:div, :id => "flash_#{name}", class: 'alert bg-'+{'notice'=>'success', 'alert'=>'danger', 'error'=>'danger'}[name].to_s) {
  msg.each do |m|
    concat m
    concat "<br>".html_safe
  end
}
```